# PDO and MySql loop outputs only one row when there are several

Tags: php, pdo

```
$stmt = $conn->prepare($sql);
$stmt->execute($array);
$rows = $stmt->rowCount();

    if($rows >= 1) {
        $x = $stmt->fetch();

        echo '<div>'.$x['heading'].'</div>';

        while($row = $stmt->fetch()) {
            echo '<div>'.$row['article'].'</div>';
        }
    } else {
        echo 'Nothing found';
    }
```

When doing like above, can you see why the loop outputs only one row when there are several? It happens when I use `fetch` twice.

Also, how can I avoid having to use `fetch` twice in there? It's fetched once, can i use that same fetched data again?

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.fetch.php fetch is for a single row. You should try fetchAll().

Comment: But the OP has a loop to fetch one row at a time. Maybe only one row has been returned?

Answer (score 1):

```
$stmt->fetchAll()
```

maybe this?

Comment: I'm not sure how this answers the question. Using `fetch()` in a while loop is perfectly fine.

Comment: fetch works fine when used alone. Add another, and there's a problem.

Comment: @Norman What is the problem with fetching more than once? This page has many examples using a while loop to fetch: http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.fetch.php

Comment: @CommuSoft Yes, but the while loop will continue to run as long as there are results in `$stmt`. It fetches one row upon each iteration until there are no more rows to fetch. I'm not sure how `fetchAll()` solves the issue here.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `fetchAll()` to get all of the data in the result set as an array.

You can reuse the data by assigning it to a variable:

```
// Fetch all returned rows
$my_rows = $stmt->fetchAll();

// Make use of these rows multiple times
foreach ($my_rows AS $single_row)
{
    echo $single_row['column_name'];
}

// Make use of the retult set a second time
foreach ($my_rows AS $single_row)
{
    echo $single_row['column_name'];
}
```

Comment: When using fetchAll, is it possible to directly access a value without the loop. Eg: $my_rows['heading']

Comment: @Norman All of your rows are fetched into the array. So you'd do `$my_rows[0]['heading']` for the first row. Try `echo"<pre>".print_r($my_rows,true)."</pre>"` to see the array structure.